# How to stub an object that still has to be loaded from the database in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocha.js

I would like to check whether an object's association receives a certain method call. Problem is that I can stub the object's association, but when later on, the association is loaded from the database, the loaded object is not the same "fysical" object as my stubbed object. It has the same ID, but it is not the same "fysical" object, so the stub doesn't work anymore.

What I currently have is (and this works!)

```
  it "should register the payment of the invoice if everything ok" do
    invoice = create(:invoice)
    # Dirty trick to get exactly this instance as invoice of the created financial transaction
    FinancialTransaction.any_instance.stubs(:invoice).returns(invoice)
    invoice.expects(:register_payment).with(invoice.derived_total_cost)
    post :create, :financial_transaction => attributes_for(:financial_transaction, invoice: invoice, amount: invoice.derived_total_cost)
  end
```

where the second line "guarantees" that I will get the same fysical object. This works, but I consider it a "dirty" solution, as I have to stub FinancialTransaction.any_instance, where in fact I should stub the not-yet-existing financial transaction.

What I would like to have is a way to write something like

```
  FinancialTransaction.instance_with_id(id).expects(:register_payment)
```

Question is: how can this be done?

Comment: I would suggest rewriting your question so that you show what your code is and what problems you have instead of writing pseudo-code that does not seem to work (and I am not able to understand). That way, somebody might be more likely to help you.

Comment: @Phoet: I modified the question as to give some more info

Comment: i'm still confused. what does the code look like that you want to test and what is your expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this as follows

```
  let!(:invoice) { create(:invoice) }
  let!(:financial_transaction) { create(:financial_transaction, invoice: invoice) }

  before(:each) do
    FinancialTransaction.stubs(:new).returns(financial_transaction)
  end

  it "should register payment of the invoice if everything ok" do
    invoice.expects(:register_payment).with(invoice.derived_total_cost)
    post :create, :financial_transaction => attributes_for(:financial_transaction, invoice: invoice, amount: invoice.derived_total_cost)
  end
```

This way I can control the associated invoice being used, and as such, can also bind the expectation immediately to this invoice

Answer (score 0):

[Here's an article](https://bitspire.me/stub-active-record-finders-in-your-controller-tests-b8a18fb90b76) outlining some best practices along the same lines as you were thinking.