# How do I use rspec should_receive on an object created in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In an rspec controller spec, how can I use should_receive on an object created in the controller?

My understanding is that the should_receive would have to be called BEFORE the action is called, and at that point, the object doesn't exist. How is this done?

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243833/how-to-stub-an-object-that-still-has-to-be-loaded-from-the-database-in-rspec

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the `any_instance` method.

```
User.any_instance.should_receive(:name).and_return('John Doe')
```